# Cannot access key in array (or ArrayObject)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

When I dump my variable, I get following

```
ArrayObject #3482
    3 => stdClass #4bd5
    |  value => 1
    4 => stdClass #0eb8
    |  value => 1
```

but when I try to access any index and/or check key's existence, any function returns `FALSE`.

I have tried `array_key_exists`, `isset()`, `$var->offsetExists()`.
It's even more weird, that I have been using similar technique before in the same codebase.

Comment: How are you accessing a key? Please add the code with which you try to access the data.

Comment: I've tried `$var->offsetGet(3)` and `$var[3]` .. none of which works..

Answer (score -1):

Do you use offsetGet method ?

```
var_dump($var->offsetGet(3));
var_dump($var->offsetGet(4));
```

EDIT :

I have tried this and it is working perfectly

```
<?php

$obj1 = new \stdClass();
$obj1->value = 1;

$obj2 = new \stdClass();
$obj2->value = 1;

$arrayObject = new \ArrayObject();
$arrayObject->offsetSet(3, $obj1);
$arrayObject->offsetSet(4, $obj2);

var_dump($arrayObject->offsetGet(3));
var_dump($arrayObject->offsetGet(4));
```

Comment: I get a notice - `Undefined offset: 3`